# CSS Button Animation - How to Accomplish?

Tags: html, css

I found this site:
http://www.hue.pl/portfolio

It has really nice button animations. If you hover over "Branding" for example (on the right side next to the big `Chwalimy się!` text). How can I accomplish this animation and what is it called?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Question "What have you tried?":**

```
<style>
a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:after {
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
</style>

<a href="" title="Hi all">Hi all</a>
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried

Comment: @JNF Updated the post

Comment: Let's say that site changes tomorrow. You won't have an example anymore, so your question would become useless. You should insert any graphic example for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voila!

```
a {
    display:inline-block; 
    font-size:60px; 
    line-height:1.5em; 
    position:relative; 
    color:green
}
a:before {
    content:attr(title); 
    display:block; 
    position:absolute; 
    width:0; 
    height:1.5em; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    color:red; 
    transition:all 1s linear;
}
a:hover:before {width:100%;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s3f9y560/1/

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using an `after` pseudo-element with width set to zero.On hover change its width to 100%

```css
body{
    font-family:"Helvetica neue",sans-serif;
}

.text{
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    position:relative;
    line-height:50px;
    background:tomato;
    font-size:20px;
}

.text:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:"Hover Me!!";
    width:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#fff;
    background:tomato;
    transition:.5s all;
    left:0;
    font-size:20px;
}

.text:hover:after{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Hover Me!!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 issues with your code:

1. Add `position: relative;` to the `a` element. This will set the starting position for the `a:after` pseudo-element's absolute positioning.
2. You need to add `a:hover:after { width: 100%; color: #f00; }`. I think you just forgot to post this code? This is the hover-state. Without this, there will be no change.
3. If your text has a space in it, you need to add `&nbsp;` (*non-breaking space*). Otherwise, while the width grows from 0% to 100%, it will start on two lines.

Here is my solution based off of your code: http://codepen.io/n3ptun3/pen/ZbNQeg

And here's a version with slightly nicer styling: http://codepen.io/n3ptun3/pen/XmwXJv

Comment: Nice, thanks for that! Helps alot. I'm using it for a `li` menu, so I don't need to add the `&nbsp;` but great tip. Never thought of it.